# How downvote and upvote really works?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, up-votes

Today I downvoted an answer so it went from 0 to -1

But I realised it was by mistake so I upvoted the same answer again but this time the value went up to +1.

I was expecting this to be zero.

I have attached the image.

[image: Vote Up/Down]

**EDIT**

When I refreshed the page it came back to 0 again.

Comment: Don't upvote. Click on the downvote again to undo it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to click on the downvote to **un** downvote.

Clicking on the upvote upvotes the post.